# How can I use GoogleMap JavaScript API in iOS app?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps

Google provides [an iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/ios/) for GoogleMap, however, [GoogleMap JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/web/) provides more functionality including [custom styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/styling-the-base-map) and [data visualisation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/importing_data), which are features I want to achieve in my app.

So is there any way to utilise these JavaScript API in my app?

I am thinking whether I can embed the map in a WebView so that I can do JavaScript stuff in the app? Is this possible? How is the performance harm?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am using AFNetworking framework. I made subclass of it. CUK_Client is name of the subclass.

[google api  examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints) show the type of them methods (POST or GET).

You can modify according to your needs.

makeRequestGet is a generic GET method you can call it with any parameters and routes as you like. For example in getDirection method I use it for taking direction between two coordinates.

.h file

```
@interface CUK_Client : AFHTTPSessionManager
+ (CUK_Client *) sharedClient;
+ (CUK_Client *) googleMapsClient;

- (void)makeRequestGet:(NSString *) route withParamaters:(NSDictionary *)parameters completion:(DefaultIdResultBlock) completion ;

- (void)getDirection:(NSDictionary *)params completion:(DefaultIdResultBlock) completion;

- (void)beaconsVisited:(NSArray *)beacons completion:(DefaultIdResultBlock) completion;
@end
```

.m file

```
@implementation CUK_Client

+ (CUK_Client *) googleMapsClient {
static CUK_Client *googleMapsClient = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once (&onceToken , ^ {
    googleMapsClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/"]];

});

return  googleMapsClient;
}


  - (void) makeRequestGet:(NSString *) route withParamaters:(NSDictionary *)parameters completion:(DefaultIdResultBlock) completion {

    [self GET:route
   parameters:parameters
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

          return completion ( nil ,responseObject );

      } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

          return completion ( [error localizedDescription] , nil );
      }];
}

-(void)getDirection:(NSDictionary *)params completion:(DefaultIdResultBlock)completion {

        [self makeRequestGet:@"maps/api/directions/json" withParamaters:params completion:completion];
    }

@end
```

Comment: Hi @Kivannc, thank you for your answer. However, I am not just making HTTP request to the web service API, but actually I need to execute JavaScript directly. So I am now considering using UIWebiview's 
- stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: to do so.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: